# Removing first element of array if it contains only one or more spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a file with values like these:

```
 235 231 53t242354
  45 234   2354235
   3  53
```

I turn each line into an array using this expression:

```
 //Split on one or more spaces
 let arr = line.split(/\s+/);
```

In cases where the first column starts with spaces, the first column in the array will contain the spaces.  How do I detect and remove the first column in this case?

Comment: Where's the code that creates `line`?

Comment: Your question title is not clear. Please do your best to explain what's going on and the desired output.

Comment: Please see the answer utilizing trim().  That solves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove whitespace

```
let arr = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `match` with this regex: `/\S+/g` (`S` in uppercase) that matches non-space sequence of characters:

```js
let line = "  56 77    90";

let arr = line.match(/\S+/g);

console.log(arr);
```